# Match combinations with Regex, except under certain conditions

Tags: javascript, regex

Let's say I want to find all periods in a sentence that are immediately followed by a space.

Like:

```
/\. /g
```

But I want to exclude them when this combination is immediately preceded by a capital "M". How could I do this?

I found out about the negative look ahead. This is what I have tried so far:

```
/(?!M\.)(\. )/g
```

This doesn't work. Not sure why...

Comment: Try: `/\. (?!M)/g`

Comment: `.\s(?!M)` does the trick

Comment: @anubhava Thank you! That works. I mistyped my question. I just had to switch the negative lookahead in your answer with the negative lookbehind.

Comment: @mstephen19 I like this answer. I am not sure how it works though...

Comment: @mstephen19: dot needs to be escaped

Comment: @anubhava whoops